# How to ensure that only my app connects to the server?

Tags: ios, security

I'm going to write an iOS app that interacts with php server. I wanna be sure that only my app  but nobody else (how is able to intercept and read my requests) can connect to the server. I mean if somebody else sends a request, this request must be denied by the server. How do i do that?

Comment: I think it can be done through your PHP script only, make the app send DeviceID, put a check in your PHP script if request is from your DeviceID then it will go inside the script, else no response..

Comment: but then someone reads traffic, sees the deviceId and sends it, and voulia, server can't reject it. or am i missing something from your idea?

Comment: How about getting a list of deviceid from server when the app run for the first time, and detain the app itself to send server request if the deviceid not found in that list of devices ?